# Trigger javascript keyboard events with code?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to fake keydown and keyup events in javascript with for example a button? So when a button is clicked (or in my case tapped) it sends keycode 32 or whatever to the browser?

Comment: Sorry, for a non-jQuery version see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/451969

Comment: I've had to deal with that before and basically the answer is no; here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883789/1907186